nginx me redirige a https sin yo decirselo
tengo un sitio configurado de laravel, y cuando intento acceder a el me lo cambia a https, he estado haciendo ping al hostname local (laravel.app) y si hace ping bien.
mi fichero conf de nginx para mi app de laravel:
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    root /var/www/html/laravel_test/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php ;

    server_name laravel.app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}

mi /etc/hosts :


127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Portatil
127.0.0.1   test.com
127.0.0.1   laravel.app

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1   kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

Y cuando pongo en el explorador web : http://laravel.app me redirecciona a https://laravel.app y me sale esto en el explorer web:

si hago ping :
PING laravel.app (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms

Haciendo un wget laravel.app :
--2024-11-15 15:56:18--  http://laravel.app/
Conectando con 127.0.0.1:3128... conectado.
Petición Proxy enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: no especificado [text/html]
Guardando como: “index.html”

index.html                          [ <=>                                                   ]  26,85K  --.-KB/s    en 0s      

2024-11-15 15:56:18 (514 MB/s) - “index.html” guardado [27498]

Con sudo, haciendo : sudo wget laravel.app :
--2024-11-15 16:09:08--  http://laravel.app/
Resolviendo laravel.app (laravel.app)... 127.0.0.1
Conectando con laravel.app (laravel.app)[127.0.0.1]:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: no especificado [text/html]
Guardando como: “index.html”

index.html                          [ <=>                                                   ]  26,85K  --.-KB/s    en 0s      

2024-11-15 16:09:08 (685 MB/s) - “index.html” guardado [27498]

AL ejecutar curl http://laravel.app -Is :
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2024 18:26:23 GMT
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik94b09ja09ETTBXalNuS29OTUNOZ0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU0IvNFMyZjgxbzlxZGxvQnUwQW5hM1E5V3JQelZsbkllV09Uby9iZ1N6R0tWZEo3ZmFMSk12dlFxcVRzaTdOUTUrVHR2WHhwOFIxSElpWXpTVForalRDWURrUEdEbFZwMjUzbXA3TUZXVXNlcVNRR1NjWVJIQUJRclZ2ZUdWL0YiLCJtYWMiOiI0ZDUxZGY2MDEwNTZhY2FmZTcxZGMyMWE0MTY1OTc4OTFhM2RhNDFjNzQ4ZjBhY2M5ZWY3ZmE4MzZjNjE5YmExIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Fri, 15 Nov 2024 20:26:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Inl2bUpoa25pQTZabGdBLzJHZlVXWFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSkJCTU5mVC9Bd3JGUUE3ODFrblZuWVhidVFKdFVjNFVWUktHWjR1d0o3UDVpUkVGZmhpYjFkUmlzc2w5RzNVaFEwc3Z4VWFGakY5c0diSG1XeVZJMnpIZHorN29HdVIzVUxTbUJZVnd5dTRoZWlBMUF0LytyWWZpTXlER1ZjVUwiLCJtYWMiOiI2OTYwOTZmODFiYjcwMGIxYWE3YzY2NjEwZGQyNWI4M2U0YzUwY2RkMzllMGEzYjY0ODYyMWY2MGZjNmY1ZjhiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Fri, 15 Nov 2024 20:26:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
X-Cache: MISS from Portatil
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from Portatil:3128
Via: 1.1 Portatil (squid/4.10)
Connection: keep-alive


Tras Inhabilitar la cache chrome y haber escrito la direccion a mano me he encontrado con este dato que parece interesante:

Esta haciendo una redireccion interna. Los demas llamdas  son a https asi que no importa para este caso ya que la llamada que hago yo realmente es la de la imagen

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

Los comentarios han sido movidos al chat; por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí. Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los propósitos de los comentarios. Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una respuesta, en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

He dejado una perolata en el chat, revísala a ver si te ayuda.

@masterguru no me sale nada en el chat

Pues yo si que lo veo:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156240/discussion-on-question-by-josanangel-nginx-me-redirige-a-https-sin-yo-decirselo... quizás me he equivocado de "room", pero bueno, lo tienes en esa, míralo

@masterguru ya lo solucione, simplemente cambien el nombre laravel.app por otro , como myapp.com , y funciono, no me preguntes porque

Por la cache seguramente, ya te lo digo yo... no la limpiastes bien antes seguramente.. piensa que las cabeceras 301, etc, se quedan allí y para borrarlas hay que hacerlo de forma distinta al resto de archivos... ahora, al cambiar el nombre, no tenias cacheado eso y te ha funcionado bien

laravel.app es un dominio existente que tiene activado HSTS, por lo cual, aunque lo declares localmente como apuntando a tu localhost, igual obedecerá la regla HSTS que indica que siempre debe ser servido por HTTPS.
Para verificar esto, puedes ir a chrome://net-internals/#hsts
En la casilla bajo Query HSTS/PKP domain  ingresa laravel.app y verás el informe que dice (extracto)
static_sts_domain: app
static_upgrade_mode: FORCE_HTTPS
static_sts_include_subdomains: true

